# how to average all rows of the data set when a certain column's row has similar value

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the Time column there are two 18 values so i want to average those two rows which contain that 18 value. 
[this is a picture of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II1hS.png)

Comment: Do you only care about the 18? If you want the average of all groups, you want a `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have your columns and rows indexed in your actual code, how the table was generated, etc. so you can't just copy and paste this but something in this vein might work.

```
    for i in time
        if i==i+1:
            rows[i]=(rows[i]+rows[i+1])/2
            rows.remove(rows[i+1]
        else:
            pass
```

Again, this code will almost certainly not work as is.  It's basically pseudocode in python syntax.  I have no idea what your code looks like so I can't provide anything more specific, but it could give you an idea of how to approach this sort of problem.

Comment: i have millions of rows and this loop is going to be very slow

Comment: @MridulNigam If you want useful answers, you should be posting code samples, pseudocode, an idea of what context this is being done in, something other than a picture of a table.  Otherwise you aren't going to get much that is specific to your needs.  A table provides almost no information.  Something like for i in time: ind = numpy.where(i==i+1), could feed you an index array that could be used in a similar fashion.  Again, it's hard to provide more without more info.